# lua text interface library (i.e., writing a custom shell in lua)

Tags: lua, terminal, text-parsing

Specifically, something which automates the drudgery along the lines of Perl's [Term::Shell](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term%3a%3aShell)

Failing that, are there any good parsing libraries which would suit such a project?

I have a need to wrap an OEM-provided tool -- which, while usable, is utterly baroque -- in something a little friendlier to the human brain.

Thanks to all who reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, depending of your lua implementation, but the os.execute() function allow to call a shell function on your system (i do not know though if it will work since you are working on embedded device), but a custom shell is easy to write in Lua from scratch.

Just get the user input using **io.read()** / **io.write()** functions, then you can parse the user commande using such function :

```
function string.split(self,c)
local l , c , b = {} , c or " " , self
while b:find(c) do
    table.insert(l,b:sub(0,({b:find(c)})[1]-1))
    b = b:sub(({b:find(c)})[1]+(#c))
end
if not(b == "") then table.insert(l,b) end
    return l
end
```

The command name is given by the first token of the table, and all the arguments are following, dealing with **table** functions and **unpack()** parsing will be very fast to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If your OEM has a C interface, consider writing a [binary module](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BinaryModuleTutorial) instead. That way you will be able to use the default lua console:

```
$: lua

Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> oem = require 'baroque-oem'
> oem.foo('bar')
```

Comment: It's not in order to programatically access the interface (which, btw, they don't provide C bits for), but for customers who need to access the interface, but don't want to have to map hexadecimal codes to meanings for a command-line tool. The goal is to provide a polished, intuitive shell-alike for performing tasks on the system. If this works out, it is likely that this would become a standard tool for providing textual UIs for our customer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the difference between "programatically accessing the interface" and "access the interface". I also don't know what you mean by "hexadecimal codes". In addition, if you don't have a C interface, how do you want to manage the app from Lua? You might want to add more information to your original question.

Comment: That was possibly poorly worded; I want to implement a shell analogue in lua (embedded device, and memory is at a premium) which provides a friendlier interface to the command-line management tool the manufacturer provided. And by hexadecimal codes, I mean hexadecimal codes which the user types in as command-line arguments.

Comment: I don't think there is anything already built-in in Lua to handle that; especially if you are in an embedded device. Those things tend to have their own input/output subsystems.

Comment: I am not asking for a library to do I/O on an embedded device; the system already has a minimal shell which can spawn applications; I'm asking if there is a lua library which can provide the same text input style as a regular unix shell.